# SELECT ALL records FROM each TABLE ORDER BY PRIMARY KEYS(EID,CID,FID,EnID) descending order

Tags: sql, oracle

need a SQL statement that selects all records from each table ORDER BY the primary key in descending order.

This doesn't give the complete statement

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows counter FROM user_tables;
```

I've already tried:

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows counter FROM user_tables;
```

I expect to list the output of all 4 tables in descending order ORDER BY EID, CID,FID AND ENID WHICH ARE THE PRIMARY KEYS

Comment: Hey Donna, what are the four tables called?

Comment: you need a union `select * from table_one union all select * from table_two union all select * from table_three union all select * from table_four order by edit, cid, fid, enid`

Comment: The 4 tables are Engineers, Staff, Classes and StudentEnrollments

Comment: What is a "record" in this context? It is not a technical term in Oracle SQL. Many people use it to mean "row", but in your problem that doesn't seem to be what you are asking about.

Comment: Select * FROM TABLE (ENGINEERS) union all
(select * from TABLE (STAFF) union all select * from (CLASSES)
union all select * from TABLE (STUDENTENROLLMENTS) 
ORDER BY EID, cid, fid, enid);

Comment: THIS GAVE AN  ERROR: ORA - 00904: "EID" INVALID IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union for this...

```
SELECT EID AS ID, 'Engineers' AS TableName FROM Engineers
UNION
SELECT SID, 'Staff' FROM Staff
UNION
SELECT FID, 'Classes' FROM Classes
UNION
SELECT ENID, 'StudentEnrollments' FROM StudentEnrollments
ORDER BY 1
```

In this case "ORDER BY 1" means the first column.

Comment: tHANK YOU! tHIS WORKS, BUT IS MISSING AN EXPRESSION. i'M WORKING ON THIS